# Web vs. Mobil Development: data storage

Tags: javascript, ios, web

Curious is it possible to store data / records in web development permanently in browser?

I am developing native apps for iOS, and want to understand how web / javascript works.

Usually when app in native development is downloaded first from App Store and **first it is launched, client fetches a lot of data from server**, and afterwards at **next** launches when app is running **only record changes** moves back and forth. Is it possible these kind of data transfers in web development?

In iOS development Core Data is kind a of a ORM local database, on which JOIN operations can be performed. Is it any **local database** on web development that provide **JOIN like operation**?

Answer (score 0):

Web SQL provides a local database that can be queried using SQL. But not all web browsers may support this feature.

You can check the support here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage

You can also store data locally using local storage, but this method does not use SQL.

Comment: Websql is also deprecated

Comment: so webSQL is not fully supported accross browsers, .. and not even an ORM based system

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several mechanism for storing data in browser. Check this out : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

There are of course simpler solutions as well, such as localStorage. Websql is interesting too, although it is deprecated.

Of course, there are ORMs for client side storages as well, such as http://couchdb.apache.org